Mobile App server side application uses MS Dev Tunnel, 3rd party redirect URL tries to use localhost
I'm building a mobile app using Maui, server side is set up to do all the authentication using Identity (local + 3rd party). I use a dev tunnel to communicate from the mobile app to the server, which works. There are 2 external 3rd party web sites that need to open, so both are accessed via Maui (mobile) -> Server (web view) -> 3rd party (given a return url). The first is my billing using stripe which allows me to pass in a value for the return url. I give it the url for my dev tunnel (https://******-7117.use.devtunnels.ms/paymentsuccess) and everything works. Google auth follows a similar flow, but it doesn't have an option for giving it a return url. It does have a CallbackPath option, but this is a relative url. It must get the baseUrl implicitly. So when google authenticates and tries to call back to my server app, it is trying to redirect to https://localhost:7117/signin-google which my mobile app can not access so I get a not found error. Is there anyway to specify the base URL passed to google auth as my dev tunnel url?
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddGoogle(o =>
        {
            var googleAuthNSection = configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
            o.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"]!;
            o.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"]!;
            o.SaveTokens = true;
            o.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })

